# Scale the parent layout of an eddittext as its height grows with text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-toolbar

[image]I have a toolbar at the bottom of my activity with an edittext. I'd like the toolbar's height to scale to match the growing height of the edittext. More like the photos below depict.
How do I achieve this?
[image: Normal View]

[image: Expanded view]

Here's my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/bttm_toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_bttm" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bttm_toolbar"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_transparent_bttn"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:singleLine="false" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bttm_toolbar"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_transparent_bttn"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bttm_toolbar"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_transparent_bttn"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_black_24dp" />
```

Comment: You should post your layout. Anyway regular edit text with multiline attribute set can achieve your request.

Comment: I've added my layout

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
android:isScrollContainer="true"     
android:minHeight="120dp" 
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `EditText` and set attributes singleLine="false", minLines="1", maxLines="3". Set height to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Already done this. It is not the problem. This EditText is ontop of a Toolbar. As you can see from the screenshot I've added, the toolbar doesn't scale with the EditText